# Django : GAE : non rel : maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I was learning django with GAE. Tutorial link: http://f.souza.cc/2010/08/flying-with-django-on-google-app-engine.html

Can anyone please tell me the reason? Why am I getting this error?

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/subclassi
  return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/subclassi
  return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.
  return connection.creation.db_type(self)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: Diagnosing the issue will be easier if you post complete lines from the traceback (not truncated to 80 chars), and possibly a few more lines.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you downloaded your sources, but they may be out of date.  django-nonrel is hosted on github now.

I haven't tried following these instructions, but they're newer:

http://seperohacker.blogspot.ca/2012/04/installing-django-nonrel-easily.html